# What are the possible CCA attacks on RSA with r||m+G(r) as the padding?

Tags: rsa, padding, chosen-ciphertext-attack

I was trying to come up with simple padding functions for the RSA, then trying to break them just to have a better understanding of why we need all the pieces used in the RSA OAEP... So, I am considering the following.

Let $N = p\cdot q$, $pk = e$ and $sk = d$ be the RSA parameters and keys, as usual.

Now, let $n = \lceil \log_2 N \rceil$ be the number of bits of $N$ and $k < n$ be some extra parameter controlling the padding. Let $G:\{0,1\}^k \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{n-k}$ be some mask generating function. Then, define the padding as sampling a random value $r$, computing $G(r)$ and xoring it with the message, then concatenating $r$ with the result of the xor. That is,

Padding $P: \{0, 1\}^{n-k} \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^n$ of a message $m$

1. Sample $r$ uniformly from $\{0, 1\}^k$
2. Compute $u := G(r) \oplus m$ (bit wise XOR)
3. Output $r + 2^k \cdot u$ (this is the same as $r || (G(r) \oplus m)$, i.e., concatenation)

Then, to encrypt a message $m \in \{0, 1\}^{n-k}$, we would output $c = P(m)^e \bmod N$, that is, padding then usual RSA encryption.

Now, let's say that the decryption just takes $c$ and tries to output $m$. That is,
$Dec: \mathbb{Z}_N  \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^{n-k}$ is

1. Compute $x = c^d \bmod N$
2. Compute $r' = x \bmod 2^k$
3. Compute $u' = (x - r') / 2^k$
4. Compute $G(r')$
5. Output  $u' \oplus G(r')$

It is clear that if $c$ is a valid ciphertext, then the decryption is correct. But for a ciphertext encrypting something that does not correspond to a valid padding, the output will be a somewhat random message, but the decryption is always well-defined.

Now, I was wondering how one can use a decryption oracle to mount an attack that shows that this padding plus RSA is not CCA2-secure.